# how can we know the JeditorPane associated with a document in the documentEvent

Tags: java, swing, text, jeditorpane

To chain block of texts in a desktop java application, I Have inherited from the JEditorPane to make blocks ot text. My problem is that in the **documentEvent** I need to retrieve informations associated with the associated **JEditorPane**. But I don't understand the way to make the link between the documentEvent and the JEditorPane.
Thank's for your help

Comment: *"My problem is that in the documentEvent I need to retrieve informations associated with the associated JEditorPane."* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Also note that a `DocumentEvent` originates from a (single) document, but that single `Document` may be in any number of `JEditorPane` components..

Answer (score 1):

No way. The Document is just a model. The same document instance could be set to multiple JEditorPanes.

```
jEditlorPane2.setDocument(jEditlorPane1.getDocument())
```

You can get list of all JEditorPane instances existing and iterate through the list checking whether Document instance equals to jEditorPaneInstance.getDocument()